# php switch case problem

Tags: php, switch-statement, evaluation

I am trying to say `$level > -100 && $level < 100`

```
$level  = 0;

                switch($level){                                                                                       

                case $level > -100:                                                                                   
                break;
                case $level <  100:                                                                                   
                break;
                default:
                echo '5';
                return null;                                                                                          
                }
```

can you use a switch statement like this.

Comment: Check my answer. It is possible using Switch. But I have to tell you, it is not a Good use of Switch.

Comment: See my comment to nikic's answer

Comment: I don't see how the proposed switch construct approximates (($level > -100) && ($level < 100)). You have 3 cases, the first of which catches -99, the second of which catches -110, and the third of which (default) is never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the answers presented so far have **explicitly** connected the spirit of the original question with a proper switch construction. So, for the record:

```
switch (true) {
    case (($level>-100) && ($level<100)):
        echo 'in range one';
        break;
    case (($level>200) && ($level<300)):
        echo 'in range two';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'out of range';
}
```

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this usage of switch.

Comment: Did you forgot break statement?

Comment: Yes indeed I did! Thanks, I added them.

Answer (score 4):

When you say `switch ($level)` you're already comparing the value of `$level`. Each `case` can then only check for equality, you can't do comparisons like in your example. You'll have to use an `if` statement instead:

```
if ($level > -100 && $level < 100)
  ; // do nothing; equivalent of break in this case
else
  echo '5';
```

Even simpler, just negate the conditions:

```
if ($level <= -100 || $level >= 100)
  echo '5';
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart of if/else, another way to do it:

```
switch (true)                                                                               
    case $level > -100:
        break;
    case $level <  100:
        break;
    default:
        echo '5';
        return null;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really same as `$level > -100 && $level < 100`. Consider `$level = -200`. It will not break on first case, but will break on second one. Actually `echo 5;` line will never be reached.

Comment: @Mchl - You're right, but this is actually a bug in the original question. The answer from NikiC is syntactically correct, and is presumably what the asker was wanting to do.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are both correct and incorrect at the same time. Incorrect, in that it is possible to do what you want in PHP... change `switch($level)` to `switch(true)` and your example will work. Correct, in that it's bad form and if any other programmers see that in your code they'll probably come after you with pitchforks. Its not how the switch statement is intended to be used, and wouldn't work like that in most other languages.

Comment: I think thats interesting. The fact you can set the switch to true and evaluate for it is clearly intentional. It also when you think about it makes perfect sense. What I would not call it is intuiative.Alas it does seem a case resulting in raptors falling from the sky.

Comment: I don't agree that switch(true) is bad form in PHP. It *is* true that some other languages (like Java) don't support the switch(true) syntax. But plenty of languages *do* support similar constructions (including Perl, Groovy, and Go), so you can't really make the argument that "nobody else does this, so neither should you". And I claim that when properly used it can actually make PHP code at least as easy to read as a chain of if/then elses.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Switch does only 'equals' type comparison.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The `switch` statement needs literals in the `case` blocks. Use an if statements instead:

```
if(!($level > -100 && $level < 100))
{
  echo '5';
  return null;
}
```

Comment: how can level be less than -100 and more than 100?

Answer (score -3):

This is one of the reasons people advocating `case` as a superior solution to `if-else` are off base. I don't like the syntax or the limitations -  `if-ifelse-else` is much more useful.

Comment: this doesn't help with the question at all.

Comment: Neither one is "superior" to the other; each has its own uses. In this case, an `if` statement wins.

Comment: my apples can beat up your oranges.

Comment: It's just argumentive. Both statements have their merits.

Comment: I said 'I don't like' which is clearly meant to be known as an opinion.  I guess my answer should have been left as a comment, sorry. It's a fact that `switch` is more limited, and that it has a syntax different than other control structures, including the oft-missed `break` (which can cause problems).  This isn't apples and oranges, to compare a control structure.  `if` is clearly superior overall, since it can do the same thing and a lot more. I'd like to see which one you could do entirely without.